# Button tapped animation will only play randomly

Tags: swiftui

This is a minimum reproducible problem. I have a list of buttons, each button has some text and image inside. When the button is tapped, the "tap" animation should play (greying out). But this only happens randomly. Maybe 1 every 2 times.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                print("hello")
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    Image("art")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                    Text("hi")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(
                            EdgeInsets(top: 45, leading: 15, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
                        )
                }
                .frame(height: 90)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
```

How to fix? Note that even when animation doesn't play, hello still get printed.

Comment: You're speaking of the default animation when tapping a button, correct?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: I'm seeing the same testing on an iphone. In my tests, a soft or quick tap doesn't trigger the button animation although the print works. But a slightly longer tap(not long press) does have the animation. With light taps, the gesture recognizer doesn't seem to know whether to scroll or have a tap animation. Seems this may be intentional.

Comment: Right but thats not the case for other buttons I've seen in a list. For example in Apple's settings app there are a ton of buttons that are responsive.

Comment: Oh yes. The problem seems to be related to the .buttonStyle(.plain) whether in a form or list. Without it, the tap is consistent as in Settings.

Comment: But I need it to be .plain because otherwise the whole row highlights when tapped, I need the button to highlight.

Comment: yes, I see the dilemma. 'Just trying to clarify the specifics for anyone who might have an answer.